# Invalid parameters in Kmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I need to create a machine learning model to predict if a person survives in the Titanic or not. There are two files: the training file and the testing file. I never used `KMeans` before so I used parameters that I found in tutorials:

```py
clf = KMeans(n_clusters=10)

acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf,parameters, scoring=acc_scorer)
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But I get an error message:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter criterion for estimator KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=10, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Comment: Does the exception occur in this line  `clf = KMeans(n_clusters=10)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is in R. 
The kmeans function takes atleast 2 arguments 
     1. The dataset that it has to operate on 
     2. and the no of initial centroids

This is  the documentation says (for 2.0.4 version)
**Usage:**

```
KMeans(x, centers, iter.max=10, num.seeds=10)
```

**Arguments**

**x**

```
A numeric matrix of data, or an object that can be coerced to such a matrix (such as a numeric vector or a dataframe with all numeric columns).
```

**centers**

```
The number of clusters in the solution.
```

**iter.max**

```
 The maximum number of iterations allowed.
```

**num.seeds**

```
The number of different starting random seeds to use. Each random seed results in a different k-means solution.
```

for more info [refer](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rcmdr/versions/2.0-4/topics/KMeans)

Comment: It is in python. So sorry, forgot to specify that

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if the `GridSearchCV` parameters contain an invalid option. In more-recent versions of `scikit-learn` (here: `scikit-learn==1.2.0`) the error message should show *which* parameter was incorrect:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, _ = make_moons(noise=0.1)

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=10, n_init="auto")
parameters = {"bad_init": ("k-means++", "random")}

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters).fit(X)
```

`bad_init` is not a parameter that `KMeans` can take, so the `ValueError` informs us of this:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'bad_init' for estimator KMeans(n_clusters=10, n_init='auto'). Valid parameters are: ['algorithm', 'copy_x', 'init', 'max_iter', 'n_clusters', 'n_init', 'random_state', 'tol', 'verbose'].
```